# midnight commander: VFS does not work for tar.xz

Tags: midnight-commander

In my `mc.ext` I have following rule for `tar.xz` files:

```
regex/\.t(ar\.xz|xz)$
    Open=%cd %p/utar://
    View=%view{ascii} xz -dc %f 2>/dev/null | tar tvvf -
```

But, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in `mc` on `foo.tar.xz` file, `mc` shows the file as empty. This works fine for other archives, such as `.tar.gz`. I have `xz-utils` installed. Do I need another package for this to work?